# What type of string lasts in strong UV and pool environment?

Tags: materials

I need to use a string near or in a pool for one summer. It has to last strong summer heat (TX), sun, UV rays, and pool chlorine.

My chlorine dispenser float keeps going next to the skimmer area. Some people say high chlorine levels can damage pump and other equipment. So I thought of reeling it and attaching to the opposite side of the skimmer. The float will weigh much less than 4 lb. when in water but better safe than sorry.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Any of the "pool" ropes mentioned below should work. Whatever you buy will probably A) last at least a couple of years, and B) will be in large enough quantity that you won't need all of it - when the piece in the pool wears out, replace it with a another piece that you've had stored away from the heat, UV & chlorine.

Comment: Agree with @FreeMan. Now that we better know what it's for, I'd say it's not too critical, and you'd easily inspect it as you use the pool.

Comment: Frankly, just about anything cheap would work to tether it to the other side of the pool. If/when the tether breaks down, get more. Use something cheap...

Comment: @FreeMan Pipes get clogged up easily. So I don't want it to break up into the pool.

Comment: having the dispenser close to the skimmer will not significantly increase chlorine levels in the pump.

Answer (score 3):

**Nylon** and **polyester** are typically considered the most UV-resistant rope materials.  However, neither do particularly well with Chlorine. **Polypropylene** is better with Chlorine, but degrades in sunlight. It has the benefit of flotation, so it's widely used in pool applications. You may need to replace it annually.

Answer (score 3):

*Solid braid nylon rope* is used for float lines in pools, commonly used in lane separators.

You can buy it in a variety of lengths and diameters.

Answer (score 2):

I use bracelet string they are very resilient to corrosion. Normally made from Nylon and Satin.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. You should improve this answer because as it stands it is being flagged as low quality and is in danger of being deleted. I would suggest as a minimum if you could provide information or experience that the material that you suggest is suitable for use in the questioners pool environment. It could also be useful to attest to the strength of the material.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/129427)

Comment: Sure it does, @FreeMan. Two viable materials are suggested.

Answer (score 1):

The thread they use to sew shade cloths together would be about right.

fishing line would work too, but knots are tricky.

Comment: Both suggestions are rather vague. Fishing line in particular is a great many things these days. You should specify material, not usage.